# ContainerView + lookupFactory not working in EmberJS 1.2.0+

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have existing code in my application that has been working up until version 1.2.0 of EmberJS.

I'm extending a ContainerView and using a lookupFactory call to look for names of templates, creating the childView using that found template and pushing it into the childViews. I'm hooking it up to a Handlebars Helper.

This allows me to dynamically display any view I want based on the data that's passed into the container view.

Once I updated to 1.2.0 or greater, it stopped working with no errors being thrown. What do I need to change to get it working again?

[JSBin Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oFOREYe/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specify the "layoutName" property on my component definitions. Then it all magically worked again.

Thank you @rjackson!